# How does Chromecast redirect Flash video streams onto the TV?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, google-cast, chromecast

Chromecast allows us to redirect Flash video streams from the browser to the TV? Does this mean the Chromecast device itself contains a Flash player? Or is Google translating the video on a server somewhere into HTML5 video?

What's the best way to determine this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromecast does not contain flash.  Many flash players use MP4 or other common video formats that Chromecast supports.  Those who redirect Flash to Chromecast, call out from Flash to the Chromecast JavaScript API, and pass enough information for the Chromecast receiver to load the content.

Comment: thanks so how would we identify the mp4 URL a video stream is using, for instance, on espn?

Comment: If you were with ESPN, you'd have access to their Flash source code, and could easily find it and add Chromecast support.